# How to know why OCI8 have different behaviour with php_fpm and php_cli?

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I'm currently working on a PHP Symfony 3.4 project and I am connecting with OCI8 to an Oracle BDD.
Also, on the same environment I execute a .php file from command line and I connect to the Oracle bdd from it too.

I am using OID to connect to the database in my symfony app and my .php script.
Here's how I am connecting :

```
$conn = oci_connect('USERNAME', 'PASSW', 'OID_BDNAME');
```

Where OID_BDNAME is the database name in OID.

And it's working perfectly fine from the .php script but I can't get it to work within my symfony application, and here's the error :

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Both command line php and php fpm are using /etc/php.ini (I checked with `phpinfo();` and `$ php --ini`)

Do you have an Idea why OCI8 have different behaviour with php_fpm and php_cli, and how to solve this ? Thanks

Comment: PHP OCI8 needs to have some environment variables set so it can find the Oracle libraries and configuration files.  I expect you have them set in your shell, but they are not set when PHP-FPM runs.  What Oracle software do you have installed and what environment variables?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have Oracle 56 and ORACLE_HOME and TNS_ADMIN are set and availlable on both php-fpm and php_cli

Comment: Define 'available'.   How exactly are you setting these values?

Comment: Thanks. I am setting them in the fastcgi_params file and they are exported too and it's working fine with php_cli